# ProgressView showing in all items of List

Tags: ios, list, swiftui

I have List with a button to download a file in each row. When I tap to download, the `ProgressView` is showing in all rows, instead of of just one row.

Here is my code:

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<self.books.count, id: \.self) { index in
       
        VStack {
            let thisBook:Book = self.books [index]
            Text (thisBook.name)
                .font(.system(size: 22))
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            
            Button(NSLocalizedString("Download", comment: "")) {
                let downloadAudio = DownloadAudio()
                downloadAudio.downloadBookId(Int32(thisBook.bookId), 
                                             testamentId: Int32(self.testamentId), 
                                             forLanguage: self.item.language)
                { String, progress, error in
                    self.progress = progress
                    print(progress)
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .controlSize(.large)
            
            ProgressView(value: self.progress, total: 1.0).id(UUID())
    
        }
    }
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
}
```

How do I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're putting the progress in the ForEach, so it will be shown for each index. If you only want it for the selected button, you should take it out of the ForEach

Comment: The value of the progress view is always the same: `self.progress`. You need separate progress values for each book. And stop iterating the indices in `ForEach`. You don't need the index ay all. Adopt `Identifiable` in `Book`. And running asynchronous stuff in the rendering area of a SwiftUI view is bad practice anyway.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code with Identifiable in your response?

Comment: `Identifiable` is just a protocol with requires an `id` property. This property can be used in `ForEach` loops omitting the `id` parameter. A reasonable implementation depends on the knowledge of the `Book` struct.